# Open Trip Planner Real-Time Testing

Tags: java, json, opentripplanner

I am setting up a OTP instance on my local machine and I have at my disposal all the necessary feeds (Static and Real-Time). Some of these have some issues regarding the quality of data but overall they are working and being processed.

So far I have successfully been able to display static feeds and I'm trying to add real-time feeds. This is my current router-config.json

```
{
    "routingDefaults": {
        "walkSpeed": 1.5,
        "maxTransfers": 4,
        "transferSlack": 120,
        "waitReluctance": 0.99,
        "walkReluctance": 1.75,
        "stairsReluctance": 4.0,
        "walkBoardCost": 540,
        "carDropoffTime": 240
    },

    "updaters": [
        {
            "type": "real-time-alerts",
            "frequencySec": 30,
            "url": "myUrl",
            "feedId": "2"
        },
        {
            "type": "stop-time-updater",
            "frequencySec": 30,
            "url": "myUrl",
            "feedId": "2"
        },
        {
            "type": "real-time-alerts",
            "frequencySec": 30,
            "url": "myUrl",
            "feedId": "11"
        },
        {
            "type": "stop-time-updater",
            "frequencySec": 30,
            "url": "myUrl",
            "feedId": "11"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I launch OTP locally it seems that nothing is changing in my data. For example, if I put some random start and end point on the map it shows me a path but I can't tell if there is a difference between the version with and without real-time feeds.

Sometimes (not frequently) I also get these messages on the console:

```
10:43:14.163 INFO (GtfsRealtimeAlertsUpdater.java:100) Ignoring feed with an old timestamp.
```

How can I properly test if real-time data are being processed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options.

1. Make a query to the [transit index](http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.4.0/resource_IndexAPI.html#resource_IndexAPI_getStoptimesForStop_GET) and see if there are any stops that include real-time data.
2. Make 2 nearly-identical queries to the [PlannerResource](http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.4.0/resource_PlannerResource.html), except on one of them set the query param `ignoreRealtimeUpdates` to true. Then compare and see if any itineraries have different times.